Jekyll Minima on GitHub Pages: How can I sort navigation menu links?
I have very basic web development skills and am new to Jekyll (and Git/GitHub in general) so I'd appreciate answers that assume I have no pre-requisite experience or knowledge of anything unless I've mentioned it in my post. Thank you!
Overview
I have a very simple GitHub Pages website where I host my resume, portfolio, etc: https://streats.github.io/
I'm using the Minima Jekyll theme which adds a navigation menu to the top of the page. I installed Minima by referencing it in my _config.yml file:
theme: minima

By default it lists all pages in my repo, so in _config.yml I defined which pages to exclude and include.
However, the remaining links are showing in a strange order that I can't figure out how to sort.

About (about.md)
Accessibility Statement (accessibility-statement.md)
Contact (contact.md)
Writing samples (/work)
Craft notes (/craft-notes)
Case studies (/case-studies)
Welcome (index.md)
Resume (resume.md)

The order I want is:

Welcome
About
Resume
Writing samples
Case studies
Craft notes
Accessibility Statement
Contact

Troubleshooting attempt #1
I had added navigation_weight to the frontmatter of each page but I can't see where to tell my website to sort by that.
All the online troubleshooting I've found is saying to add a sort parameter to { % assign % } in the header file, but as I am referencing the theme directly in my config file (theme: minima) I don't have any theme files in my repo I can edit.
I had tried adding an  _includes directory with the header.html from the Minima repo so I could edit the header properties, but nothing seemed to change, so I don't know if I need to do something else to make my site use that header instead of what it's pulling from theme: minima. I think it wasn't enough to just add includes/header.html because maybe it refers to other stuff in other files. The GitHub Actions that runs on my builds was giving errors but I couldn't understand what the problem was and I got a bit overwhelmed so deleted the _includes .
Troubleshooting attempt #2
I had also tried renaming some of the files numerically (01_about.md, 02_resume.md, etc) and that seemed to successfully put them in order, but because some of the top level links are subdirectories (/work, /case-studies, /craft-notes) it's a faff to rename that subdirectory, and anyway it doesn't seem like a very elegant way to do it as I'd need to rename every instance of these links if I ever changed the menu order.
Here's my repo: https://github.com/streats/streats.github.io
What I need help with
This is supposed to be a very basic website so I'm looking for a very simple solution to add a navigation menu with specific links in a certain order. I'm an absolute beginner so I'd rather not have to go deep into the weeds with installing a bunch of stuff - I mainly use the GitHub UI or sometimes GitHub Desktop, as I'm not very good at command line and use it infrequently so don't really have a local environment set up, so any CL solutions aren't really ideal for me unless someone can really walk me through it from the very start.
I opened an issue on my repo to help me track things I've tried, feel free to contribute over there: https://github.com/streats/streats.github.io/issues/6
